# Datatype mismatch error because of NULL values in union operation

Tags: sql, null, union, exasol

AFAIU, an SQL engine internally assigns a datatype to `NULL` values, for example, some engines use the [datatype integer as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612696/sql-union-all-data-type-error-with-nulls). I know, that this may cause an error in `UNION` operations when the column of the other table is not compatible (e.g. `VARCHAR`) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612696/sql-union-all-data-type-error-with-nulls)). Still, I struggle to understand why the following code works/does not work (on [Exasol](https://docs.exasol.com/home.htm) DB):

**A)**

This works

```
SELECT NULL AS TEST
UNION
SELECT DATE '2022-11-03' AS TEST
;
```

**B)**

But when I do 'the same' using a subquery, it throws a `datatypes are not compatible` error.

```
SELECT A.* FROM (SELECT NULL AS TEST) A
UNION
SELECT DATE '2022-11-03' AS TEST
;
```

**C)**

B can be fixed by explicit type casting of the `NULL` value:

```
SELECT A.* FROM (SELECT CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS TEST) A
UNION
SELECT DATE '2022-11-03' AS TEST
;
```

Still, I do not understand what happens in B behind the scenes, so A works but B does not. Apparently, the subquery (or a join) makes a difference for the type of the `NULL` column. But why?

**Can anyone explain what exactly happens here?**

---

PS. The same is the case for JOINS.

**B2)**

Does not work.

```
SELECT 'Dummy' AS C1, SELECT NULL AS TEST
UNION
SELECT 'Dummy' AS C1, SELECT DATE '2022-11-03' AS TEST
;
```

**C2)**

Does work.

```
SELECT 'Dummy' AS C1, SELECT CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS TEST
UNION
SELECT 'Dummy' AS C1, SELECT DATE '2022-11-03' AS TEST
;
```

Comment: B), the data type is decided in the subquery (i.e. before analyzing the union.) Should raise an error, but your dbms instead chose a non-date compatible data type - which the union analyze doesn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `NULL` has the type `BOOLEAN` in Exasol. You can check this either by using [TYPEOF](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/typeof.htm) or [DESCRIBE](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql/desc%5Bribe%5D.htm):

```sql
select TYPEOF(NULL); -- The TYPEOF function is available since version 7.1

-- Old way to see the type of an expression:
create schema s;
create or replace table tmp as select null expr;
describe tmp;
```

However, sometimes Exasol changes this type internally. One of these cases is if a `NULL` literal occurs directly inside an `UNION` clause. It only does this if it is an explicit `NULL` literal. E.g. the following also doesn't work:

```sql
SELECT NULL+NULL AS TEST
UNION
SELECT DATE '2022-11-03' AS TEST;
```

But it works if the expected type is `BOOLEAN`:

```sql
SELECT NULL+NULL AS TEST
UNION
SELECT TRUE AS TEST;
```

As you mentioned, the workaround is to wrap the expression in a `CAST`.